# Why do we minimise a cost function instead of maximising an equivalent?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, optimization, gradient

I don't really understand why we minimise a cost function for gradient descent. Why don't we try to have something like a gradient 'climb', where we maximise some function?

Is it due to convention, or are there some properties which make minimising much better for optimisation than maximising functions?

A similar question was asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94783/why-minimize-loss-function-instead-of-maximizing-reward-function), but I don't feel like the answers really address my question directly, and in a way which I understand.